# Помогите решить простую задачу

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать код который посчитает сколько 9 в числе. Например дано число 929, должно вывести 2.

Я понимаю примерно как он может выглядь, но почему-то не получается его написать. Короче как мне кажется надо сделать цикл который будет брать остаток у числа(929 например) с помощью оператора % и проверять является ли это число 9 если да то ++, далее в цикле надо написать ((число(929))- остаток(9))/10 получится 92 которое цикл должен взять и выполнить все заново.

Мне просто надо увидеть, понять как выглядит код, чтобы я смог выполнить остальные похожие задачи, которых у меня много

Comment: И с чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Нужно вопросу давать определяющее название. После Вас тема останется... Нужно показывать, что сделали и что не получется.

Comment: @vikttur судя по голосам за закрытие - не останется

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Почему-то не могу оставить ответ, если я правильно понял, вот что вам нужно: <div id="source">929</div>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>

var source = document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var pattern = /9/g; 
var resultArr;


if ( source != undefined ) {

  resultArr = source.match(pattern);
  result.innerHTML = "В числе " + source + " всего девяток: " + resultArr.length;
  console.log (resultArr.length);
}

Comment: @l2banners <Отвечайте на вопросы высокого качества.

Comment: @0xdb А что непонятного в вопросе? Человеку нужно посчитать количество девяток встречающихся в строке. Я сейчас тоже учу регулярные выражения и мне интересно отвечать на такие вопросы, поэтому и отвечаю

Comment: @l2banners [Не на все вопросы стоит отвечать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Извините мужики, не удержался: `"929".split('').filter(x => x === '9').length`

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko, Вроде дано число, надо сначала `.toString` у него вызвать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Два достаточно простых решения "в лоб".

Первое. Преобразование в строку.

```
function count1(n) {
    var s = n.toString();
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i)
        if (s[i] === '9')
            ++result;
    return result;
}
```

Второе. Подсчёт остатков от деления.

```
function count2(n) {
    var result = 0;
    var m = n;
    do {
        var r = m % 10;
        if (r === 9)
            ++result;
        m = (m - r) / 10;
    }
    while (m != 0);
    return result;
}
```

Проверка входных данных на вашей совести. ;-)